# Google analytics session linking between mobile app and webview

Tags: webview, google-analytics, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

We have a hybrid mobile app (implemented using ReactNative) that incorporates a webview of our website for its ecommerce cart.  We have Google Analytics tracking (using the same GA property) in both the app and the website, and ecommerce tracking is enabled on the cart website.

The aim is to have ecommerce tracking (from activity in the webview) work for GA sessions that start on the native app.

Is it possible to enable something like Cross Domain tracking between between the app and the website so that a GA session started by the app will be used by the site within the webview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario isn't supported by the normal GA auto-linker plugin, but it's should be possible to do this manually by extracting the GA session id (`clientId`) from the session started on the app and passing it to the webview (eg via URL parameters), to set it explicitly as described here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain

**Google Tag Manager**

Note that if you're using Google Tag Manager in the webview, you can set `clientId` as one of the "Fields to Set" in the UA tag configuration.

You'll also need to define a custom Javascript variable to extract `clientId` from the URL (or `undefined` if it's not present or invalid, which means GA will fall back to it's normal behavior).

Comment: The question is how do we get the clientId from within the app?

Comment: @kenny Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674013/how-to-get-clientid-in-android-google-analytics-v4

Comment: Have you used this approach for a long time? Do you have any experience to share regarding how it is working?

Comment: @JohnCarter why do you think that this scenario is not supported by the auto-linker plugin?  What does prevent it to work?  We are trying autolinker and it does not work, but we would like to understand why to see if we can fix or workaround it.  We see that the _ga parameter is correctly added by the webview inside the app.  But we don't know why the browser is not reading _ga parameter (we add 'allowLinker': true to the Analytics code).  Is there any check besides the timestamp that could be blocking this?  Could it be the user agent?

Comment: Hi again.  According to Google doc https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker the _ga parameter "contains the client ID as well as the current timestamp and browser metadata encoded within it. The timestamp and metadata are used to avoid problems with URL sharing."  This is probably the problem.  Since the webview browser metadata (user agent for example) is different from the browser metadata, the _ga parameter is rejected.