# Google Analytics tracking the latest parameter value

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

In my Android app I use Google Analytics, and I have to track a single parameter for each user. I'm interested only in the latest value of this parameter (user can change it inside the app).

I thought that this could be solved with custom dimensions. I created a [user-scope dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828), but it turned out that it preserves value for current and future sessions, and values from previous sessions are unchanged (we have more that one value for a single user). This disqualifies the solution for my use.

Is there any option to track a parameter only for current value? Or is there any option to create a custom report to show only the latest value of a custom dimension for each user?

Comment: The user-scope dimension is indeed what you want. However, when requesting data via the API or UI, if you pull a report with session dimensions, you will indeed see values duplicated for those sessions. To check If that's the problem: create a custom report and request only the user-scope dimension along with the `ga:users` metric for instance. You shouldn't get duplicates then. Practically, to make this useful, you should also use another user dimension to register the User ID and pull a report with both dimensions so you can get each user's parameter.

Comment: I don't think your solution works. I created a custom report with my dimension and ga:users metric, and it still presents all dimension values (not only the latest). What I would expect is that the sum of users having all different values of the parameter is equal to the number of all users, however, it is not (now I've got 2 users in general, and 2 users listed for each parameter value).

Comment: Indeed, I would expect the same. The only thing I can think of then is that you have a problem with your tracker, that every time you send your dimensions, that they're being sent with a new client ID, so GA sees all of your requests as coming from different users. Can you send an event with the user-dimension + client id (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674013/how-to-get-clientid-in-android-google-analytics-v4) and pull a report with event+user-dimensions+users?

Comment: I don't think it sees every event as from new user, because:
1. If I change my dimension value quite fast (that they're in the same session) it changes ok. It only doubles when events are in different sessions.
2. The number of users is 2 and counter for each value of dimension is 2. If it created new userId each time, I would have more that 2 user, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 0):

**After reading the documentation again. It seems that this is the expected behaviour**. [The documentation reads](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828):

> if two user-scoped custom dimension values are set within the same
>   session, the last value set gets precedence for the current session,
>   and is applied to future sessions for that user.

**What user-scope dimensions do:**

- Overwrites multiple values within the same session (keeps last one)
- Sets the same value for future sessions (until a future session overwrites it with a different one)

**What user-scope dimensions don't do:**

- Overwrites values from previous sessions

So it's normal to see multiple values for each user if different values were set across different sessions.

**Workaround report**
You can workaround this problem by:

- Creating a report with your user-scoped parameter dimension, a time dimension (e.g. `ga:date`) and another user-scoped dimension containing the user ID so you can distinguish users
- Make a unique list of those User IDs, and for each, grab the last parameter value

That way you get to see only 1 (last) value per user. [This Google Sheets add-on should help you automate this reporting task pretty easily.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on)

Comment: I know that user-scope dimensions work like this, that's why I wrote I can't use them straightly. I'll look at the spreadsheet that you linked. Thanks.